# Array representation of Binary Tree (print method)

Tags: java, arrays, printing, binary-tree

I am done with my assignment and just want the output to look nice, so I need a print method which can print a tree structure of a binary tree (represented by an array).

In an array representation of a tree:

> if node: i
>
> Child: 2*i, 2*i+1
>
> Parent: i/2

For example, for array

```
value 10 5 8 2 3 6 7
index 1  2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Tree representation should be:

> ```
>      10
>   5      8
> 2   3  6   7
> ```

It does not have to be EXACT same representation as shown above. It can be any representation that shows the tree properly.

Can someone help me with it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty easy. For the first row, print 1. Second row, print array elements 2, 3. Third row, print array elements 4,5,6,7. Fourth row, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15. See the pattern? Each row, you print elements 2^n to 2^(n+1) - 1, where the top row is zero.

This assumes if there are some nodes without two children, those null children still use space in the array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get it!
Could you also please tell me how to compute the levels of the tree using the array?
For example if array has 1 element, its level is 1,
if 2-3 elements, level is 2, 
4-7 elements, level is 3 etc.
Is there a formula to compute it?

Comment: Since the each level has twice the previous level, the number of items in a full binary tree is a power of two (minus 1). To go the other way and find the depth, you should be able to use a base 2 logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for anyone looking.  (*I haven't written in Java for a long time)

```
public class PrintTree{
 
    
    static int PowerOf2(int power)
    {
        return (1<<power);
    }
    
    static void PrintTreeArray(int array[], int arrayLength)
    {
    int currentLevel = 0;
    int maxPerLevel = PowerOf2(currentLevel);
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        if(i == maxPerLevel-1)
        {
            System.out.println("\n");
            currentLevel++;
            maxPerLevel = PowerOf2(currentLevel);
        }
        System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
    }
    }

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        int[] array = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
        PrintTreeArray(array,15);
     }
}
```